# How to take white balls from my object?

Tags: animation

I'm doing a project, but when I decided to do an animation this happened! I don't know what to do. you can see through [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10fM2T1Eo6o5VhzAFspgngY1CS6VlVUw2?usp=sharing) the screenplay of the problem. I need help!

[image: white balls on my object]

Comment: Looks like a particle system: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/index.html

Comment: If you want to remove white balls removed, go to your ouliner (panel on top-right corner) and delete them from there.

Comment: thank youuu it worked!!!